# Return the timestamps only in Laravel Events

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

When i listen to an event, the returned timestamps of laravel is formatted like this:

```
created_at: {
  date:"2018-03-04 05:24:25.000000",
  timezone:"UTC"
  timezone_type:3
  }
```

How can i return the timestamps only in laravel events or like this:

```
2018-03-04 05:24:25.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$dateTime = $object->created_at->toDateTimeString();
```

Or [create an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in the model you use:

```
public function getCreatedAtStringAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->toDateTimeString();
}
```

And use it:

```
$dateTime = $object->created_at_string;
```